# Path to source map is wrong

Tags: gulp, source-maps, gulp-less, gulp-sourcemaps

I use the packages `gulp-less` and `gulp-sourcemaps`. My less file is located under `Styles/main.less`, but the generated source map points to `source/main.less` (where `source/` seems to be a prefix). How to fix this, so the source map correctly points to `source/Styles/main.less`?

My gulp task is rather simple:

```
var gulp        = require('gulp'),
    less        = require('gulp-less'),
    gulpif      = require('gulp-if'),
    sourcemaps  = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

var paths = {
    styles: [
        'Styles/**/*.less',
        '!**/*.min.css'
    ],
    wwwRoot: 'wwwroot/'
}

var isLessFile = function(file) { return /.less$/.test(file.path); }

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    return gulp
        .src(paths.styles)
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
            .pipe(gulpif(isLessFile, less()))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('.'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.wwwRoot + 'styles'));
});
```

Comment: Check `sourceRoot` option from [gulp-sourcemaps docs](https://github.com/floridoo/gulp-sourcemaps#write-options).

Answer (score 4):

`sourcemaps.write('.',{includeContent:false, sourceRoot:'../Styles'})`

Should work for you. By default you are including the source content in your sourcemap file and `sourceRoot` is probably *'/source/'* which means to use the embedded source files. `includeContent:false` will prevent embedding sources into the sourcemap file, you also have to set `sourceRoot` property to a relative path from where you save your sourcemap to where your source files are located. In my example it will look one folder up for Styles folder, this will be prefixed to all paths in your sourcemaps `sources` array.